# QTableWidget Signal and Slot move fields

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I wonder if someone knows this.

[image: Tabwidget and lineEdit fields]

as in attached pic let's say I have a tabwidget in qt designer and some lineEdit fields. What
I want to achieve is, if the user clicks on a row of the tabwidgets the values of the items will be moved to the lineEdit fields. I saw I can somehow connect them but how to achieve this with the signal and slot functionality in qt designer without programming.

Comment: Note: that is a QTableWidget, not a [QTabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html). They are two *completely different* things.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible without implementing code manually as there is no signal to send the text. The logic is:

```
    self.tableWidget.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self.handle_cellDoubleClicked)
    # or self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.handle_cellDoubleClicked)

def cellDoubleClicked(self, row, column):
    item = self.tableWidget.item(row, column)
    text = item.text() if item is not None else ""
    self.lineEdit.setText(text)
```